# How can i disable the prepareForSegue and DidSelectRow only in a cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a GADBannerView between my tableviewcells, my banner doesn't have the full width of UITableViewCell, when i clicked outside the banner in tableviewcell my application was crashed, because in the detail of tableviewcell don't have any data to receive. I tried to do a bool logic but it doesn't work:

```
if !isAd {

        let news = newsTeam[indexPath.row]
        print(indexPath.row)
        viewController.news = news

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

i set the isAd = true when i will call my Ad.xib for table view cell.

with this code i disable all the cells, when the cell who has a banner is appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tableView's delegate method you can do something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if let _ = cell as? {YOUR_AD_CELL_CLASS}{
      return
    }

  }
```

That way, whenever the cell is of type `{YOUR_AD_CELL_CLASS}` you stop further execution (put that code at the very top for an early exit).

Comment: Thanks a lot the_critic, this really work for me. thank you very much.